# Debian live is not recognizing my ssd

Tags: ssd, debian-installer

I originally tried posting this on the Debian forums, with no luck; the forum kept asking me to sign in again whenever I pressed 'post'.

My computer has not been working for the past few days. For a while, I was happily running Debian with not a single complaint until my system randomly froze and shut down. When I tried powering it back on, it told me that there was no bootable drive. Here's what I've tried so far:

1. I tried the easiest option, resetting UEFI to defaults. No luck.
2. Apparently, leaving the UEFI config open for 15 minutes makes it reset the GPT to the backup in case of corruption. This did not resolve the issue.
3. I tried to reinstall, using the same image I had originally used. Neither Calameres nor the KDE partitioner recognised my SSD.
4. I bought a new SSD. The above issue still occurred. This confirmed that there was no problem with my old disk.
5. My friend put my new SSD into his laptop. He was able to format it on Windows. It still didn't work on my computer.
6. I checked in the UEFI and somehow it did actually recognize my disk.
7. I took it to one of those dubious repair shops. They were able to put their Windows disk in and it worked. (They and my relations kept insisting that I installed Windows, which I certainly don't want to do.)

My laptop is an Acer Aspire 5, and the SSD is an NVMe.

Could anyone shed some light as to how this could have happened in the first place, and why the installer is not recognizing my disk?

I'm sorry if this is really off topic for ULSE, but at this point I'll try anything to get it working :(

Comment: If your device is nvme, was it temporarily replaced by the shop when they tested with their own disk? If not the issue still feels like a broken nvme drive, i.e. hardware failure

Comment: why does the title say "debian live" ... surely you aren't booting from removable media? speaking of which, have you tried booting a live "CD"  and see if you can read the NVME when you boot from a live "CD"

Comment: 1. Yes, they did replace it, and at the end put mine back in, if that's what you meant. Either way, the new SSD definitely isn't broken, because it worked when a friend put it in his Windows box. 2. Yes, I'm booting from live media to try to reinstall on my new SSD after my old one (seems to have) stopped booting. But both disk-related apps on the live media (KDE Partition Editor and the Calameres installer itself) completely ignore my hard disk. Should I try to install some other distro and see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've cracked it... Theoretically, at least. While trying to resolve the (genuine) issues with the last SSD, I tried resetting the UEFI to defaults, which set the SATA back to RST with Optane. This, according to the internet, does not play well with GNU/Linux. Unfortunately, I can't find the setting in the UEFI config... Even pressing  in the Main tab (which according to Acer should reveal the option in Insyde 5.0, which I have) does not reveal it. But that's not a topic for ULSE, so I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: Some Acers will not open the [whole] UEFI/BIOS menu system unless you put a password to that system. If you do, be sure to save a note of the password, otherwise your computer might get bricked if something happens and you need access via that password.